# Getting 404 Error in SignalR version 2.2.1

Tags: javascript, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, signalr-2

Following is the code for the first model I created, which works fine:

```
registerModel=new registerModel();
registerModel.contact=[]
registerModel.contact.push(/* add 5 contacts */)
socket.invoke("create", registerModel);
```

However, the following code, where I add 10 contacts instead of 5, does not work:

```
registerModel.contact.push(/*add 10 contacts */)
socket.invoke("create", registerModel)
```

I get a *404 Not Found* error.

Furthermore, if I instead add 200 contacts, it then results in *Long Url error*.

Comment: It would help if you showed a full stack trace for the error.  From the one line error message, it is not clear which statement the error is occurring at.

Comment: I don't see any SignalR related code in your question.